# I have an App that I converted to 64 bit, but crashes on 32 bit iPad devices

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, 64-bit, simulator

As the title says, I need a way to test my App on a 32 bit iPad device, but I don't have an older device. Is there a 32 bit iPad simulator I can test on? Any tips or suggestions are appreciated  (I have the new Xcode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating an iPad 2 simulator. You can do this from Xcode > Window > Devices and clicking the + icon in the bottom right.

[image]

Using the code below, I verified that both the iPad 2 and iPad Retina simulators report being 32 bit where as the 6 reports to be 64 bit:

```
if (sizeof(void*) == 4) {
    NSLog(@"32-bit App");
} else if (sizeof(void*) == 8) {
    NSLog(@"64-bit App");
}
```

Comment: I tried this , but my App didn't crash so it didn't help.

Comment: It answers the questions, but doesn't reproduce the crash. Does it crash on all 32 bit devices 100% of the time? If so maybe you need some better steps to reproduce?